# Return back array from another component React

Tags: reactjs

So I currently have a Parent component, and a child component. The parent component consists of the following:

```
 import React, { Component } from 'react'
 import ActivityGenericFields from './activityGenericFields'
       
 class ActivityTypeSelector extends Component {
   render () {
     let activityFields = <ActivityGenericFields />
     console.log(activityFields)
     return (
       <div>
       </div>
     )
   }
 }
 
 export default ActivityTypeSelector
```

and a child component called ActivityGenericFields

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import propTypes from 'prop-types'

export default () => {

  let fields = [
    {
      active: true,
      dataType: 'Boolean',
      key: 'order',
      field: 'order',
      label: 'Private',
      order: 11,
      readOnly: false,
      mandatory: false,
    },
  ]
  return {fields}
}
```

Issue I am having is I have a console.log(activityFields) in my parent component which should return the array fields in the child component in ActivityGenericFields, however, it doesnt. It returns back an object with a series of other objects within it (key/props/ref/type/_owner/_store etc).

How do I strictly return back the fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `let activityFields = <ActivityGenericFields />` to `let activityFields = ActivityGenericFields();`. This will return your array.